# Can a vampire ghoul a carnivorous plant?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

Can a vampire use blood to ghoul a carnivorous plant, like a Venus fly trap?

Comment: In Requiem, you can ghoul certain plants, carnivorous and not. They're called *mandragora*, and have many unusual effects based on the clan of the domitor.

Comment: @Jadasc Why not post an answering comment as an answer?

Comment: @Chemus Because the querent wants a Masquerade answer, and that's not one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, according to the rules (click [HERE](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Ghoul_(VTM)) to see the White Wolf Wiki page for the Ghouls that clarify your question). 
Mortals (a "normal human being" in the classic World of Darkness, see [HERE](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_(cWOD)) for further informations) can be ghouled, and also animals, but they tend to mutate for the presence of Vitae in their system.

Citing the Wiki:

> Ghoul is a term used to describe a minion created when a vampire gives a bit of his or her vampiric vitae to a mortal without draining his or her of blood first (which would create another vampire instead).
>  ... 
> Animals can also be ghouled, a tactic particularly favored by the Nosferatu. Animal ghouls tend to grow larger and mutate, the result being a somewhat horrifying parody of the original creature. In addition, almost all ghouled animals develop a taste for blood, regardless of their original diets.

A vampire can temporarily control plants using the Thaumaturgy Path ["The Green Path"](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Thaumaturgy_(VTM)#The_Green_Path.5B7.5D).

Comment: This makes me sad :-(

Comment: Well, if you want to "control" plants, you can try ["The Green Path"](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Thaumaturgy_(VTM)#The_Green_Path.5B7.5D) of Thaumaturgy. :)

Comment: Can you quote the part of that page that you're saying answers the question? I'm not seeing anything jump-out obvious, or I would [edit] your answer to do it myself. Could you do the honours?

Comment: Edited as asked, citing both the Wiki and the section.

Comment: @ixpo I KNEW there was something with a plant somewhere. Must have remembered the green path then :)

Comment: after posting this I later found this:
Ghouls examines the life and lot of those who serve vampiric masters. From in-depth rules on being a ghoul, to ghoul families and systems for creating them, to Vitae-fed plants known as mandragora, this book fully explores the effects of the Blood on mortal lives.

http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Ghouls_(book)

Which is enough for me to start off letting my player experiment with trying to make this happen.

Comment: @lathomas64 As noted above, that's a book for Vampire: the Requiem, not Masquerade.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can but its *really* uncommon and most storytellers will not allow it. In Mexico City by Night, The Lasombra Caridad de Flores has many plant-ghouls (pp. 58).

Comment: Welcome to the site! If you haven't already, please read through [the tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). Are you able to give a page number for your reference?

Comment: Page 58 of Mexico City By Night does not say that she ghouls plants, only that she bleeds into the soil

Comment: @Tritium21 To ghoul or not to ghoul, that is the question

Comment: 100% Ghouls as the same book refers:   "The Lasombra Caridad de Flores feeds her tenebrous vitae to her plants as part of rites to honor Persephone, the Greco-Roman goddes of death. (...) Caridad Spent years breeding her GHOUL PLANTS, and they would take at least as long for anyone else to duplicate". -Mexico City By Night, page 115.